# Initialize a matrix in parallel with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a equation for every element of a matrix. Let's say a_i,j = i + j.

Is there a way I can initialize a numpy array for my matrix in parallel out of the box using numpy or do I have to use threads/other parallelization techniques? The elements are independent of each other.

Comment: Try `numba` (not *"out of the box"*) or `np.fromfunction()` (not parallel).

Comment: @MarkSetchell, don't recommend `fromfunction`

Comment: With `numpy` basics this is straight forward `np.arange(5)[:,None]+np.arange(4)` will make a (5,4) array with the `i+j1` property

Comment: Is this `i+j` the relation you want, or just a simplified example?  If you spend time with `numpy` basics you'll learn that that most operators, and many functions, work in a whole-array manner, which performs the necessary iterations in fast compiled code.  In well written `numpy` code, you shouldn't need to use python level iteration.  `broadcasting` is a powerful concept for creating 2d arrays from two 1d arrays. But you do need to take time to actually learn `numpy`.  Beyond that SO questions about numpy "vectorization" abound.

Comment: @hpaulj Its just an example. It's just that a matrix is often defined that way and I was seeking for an efficient/performant method to create a numpy array from it. Can't imagine this is that hard/uncommon in numpy.

Comment: Numpy runs *serially* except when BLAS/LAPACK functions are called (eg. matrix multiplications -- using a parallel BLAS library). *Numba* and *Cython* are the most common way to do that. *Numexpr* can also help (parallel execution by default). That being said, be aware that the RAM throughput does not generally scale with the number of core so I do not expect a huge improvement (except maybe on large computing servers -- especially NUMA ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to parallelize the initialization of this matrix and perhaps other operations, take a look at [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html). In your case, you could write something like

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

N = 100

# Initialize memory
a = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=np.int64)

@nb.njit('void(int64[:,::1])', parallel=True, cache=True) #
def initialize_array (a):
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(a.shape[1]):
            a[i,j] = i + j

initialize_array(a)

print(a[4,3]) # 7
```

Here the `prange()` indicates loops that are parallelized. But you can also just use the normal python `range()`, as Numba loops are already much faster than raw Python for loops. But really, you should only be using Numba for more complicated operations. If your goal is just to avoid slow Python for loops, you could also just do something like

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

N = 100

# Initialize memory
i = np.arange(N).reshape(-1,1)
j = np.arange(N).reshape(1,-1)

a = i + j

print(a[3,4]) # 7
```

[Note that some numpy operations will sometimes use multiple threads](https://numpy.org/install/#numpy-packages--accelerated-linear-algebra-libraries). In general, if you want to do stuff fast with numpy arrays, you have to learn to think in terms of matrix/vector operations and not in terms of for loops. Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that the second `np.prange` is useless in practice since AFAIK Numba only parallelize the outer loop. Parallelizing the inner loop would be inefficient anyway (at least with most backends including the default one).